# How to inject std::basic_istream through constructor without explicitly specifying <CharT,Traits>

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, stdtuple, type-deduction

I'm writing templated CSVParser class, that reads data from any basic_istream object and converts it to std::tuple of given types:

```cpp
template<class Ch, class Tr, class... Types>
class CSVParser {
public:
    explicit CSVParser(std::basic_istream<Ch, Tr> &istream) : istream_(istream) {

    }

     CSVParser& operator>>(std::tuple<Types...>& tup) {
        [&] <size_t... Is> (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        {
            ((istream_ >> std::get<Is>(tup)), ...);
        } (std::index_sequence_for<Types...>());
        return *this;
    }

    

private:
    std::basic_istream<Ch, Tr>& istream_;
};
```

I want it to be possible to use this way:

```cpp
const static std::string sample_csv = "1,abc\n"
                                "2,def\n"
                                "3,ghi";

std::stringstream ss(sample_csv);
CSVParser<int, std::string> parser(ss);
std::tuple<int, std::string> data;
parser >> data;
```

However, Ch and Tr types can't be deduced and I need to explicitly specify them:

```cpp
    CSVParser<char, std::char_traits<char>, int, std::string> parser(ss);
```

Is it possible in C++20 to have this pair of types deduced, and variadic `class... Types` not?
Or how can I rewrite my code to achive expecting result?

I've tried to move variadic parameter pack to the beginning of template arguments list, but compiler argues that it should be at the end.

Comment: Partial class template argument deduction does not exist. It is either all or none of the template arguments. If you want to specify some and have others deduced, you need to use a function template that forwards the arguments to construct the object, something like `auto parser = make_parser<int, std::string>(ss);`. And also, for deduction to work like this, the `Types` pack needs to come first.

Comment: However, as far as the shown template goes, `Types` doesn't need to be a template parameter pack on the class itself. It could be just on `operator>>` and then CTAD will work fine for the constructor without need to ever specify template arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `Types...` as the template parameter of `CSVParser` as the former does not contain the `tuple` member. A more appropriate option would be to make the `CSVParser` have only two template arguments

```
template<class Ch, class Tr>
class CSVParser {
public:
  explicit CSVParser(std::basic_istream<Ch, Tr> &istream) : istream_(istream) {}
  // ...
};
```

This allows you to construct a `CSVParser` from a `basic_istream` object without explicitly specifying the type

```
const static std::string sample_csv = /* */;
std::stringstream ss(sample_csv);
CSVParser parser(ss);
```

Additionally, `CSVParser::operator>>` can be simplified using `std::apply`

```
CSVParser& operator>>(auto& tup) {
  std::apply([this](auto&... elems) {
    (istream_ >>  ... >> elems);
  }, tup);
  return *this;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MTsrsKPr8)